# How to embed HTML into an email

Tags: email, sendmail, html-email

I am working on a remote server I want to pipe some HTML context to be displayed into an email.  I have been using it as follows

```
|   mail -s "subject" will@test.com
```

However when I get the email in my inbox I receive the raw HTML

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- This file was created with the aha Ansi HTML Adapter. http://ziz.delphigl.com/tool_aha.php -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xml+xhtml; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>stdin</title>
</head>
<body>
```

How do I get an email to display the HTML commands as opposed to the raw format.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You need to add MIME headers to your email to declare that body is not text/plain.  The most portable way to to generate raw email message yourself and feed it to sendmail program ("sendmail by sendmail/postfix/exim/...)

```sh
#!/bin/sh
TO=will@test.com

# feed "here document" and STDIN to sendmail
(cat <<END; cat -) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i $TO
Subject: SUBJECT
To: $TO
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

END
```

Comment: ty for the response I ended up going with mutt as I could just pass Content-type as a header.

Comment: It may be a good choice if you do not need more custom headers.